# Image wont center when width is set

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm very new in **HTML, CSS**. I'm currently using bootstrap and trying to put an image inside a row. 
I tried to center the image using `center-block` class together with `img-responsive` class but it just wont center.

Tried using `text-align: center;` method too, but the result is still the same. I noticed that when I set a width to the image, centering wont work no matter what I do. Spent whole night figuring this out, with no avail. Would love to have some insights.

my website is http://achmadhendra.byethost13.com/

Answer (score 1):

The image won't centre, because you have it wrapped within a `div` spanning only 8 columns - `col-xs-8`.

If you change this `div` to use `col-xs-12` and then give the `img` a set width, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use 'col-md-12' class and specify the image width manually.